# Question about release the object

Tags: objective-c

I have a class which contain a NSArray object.
like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface myClass : NSObject {
    NSArray *myArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *myArray;

@end
```

In .m file, I init myArray in init method,and release myArray in dealloc method.

in a method, I create its object and add it to a NSMutableArray.

```
myClass *my = [[myClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"init finish %d",[my retainCount]);
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[a addObject:my];
NSLog(@"array added finish %d",[my retainCount]);
NSLog(@"array added finish %d",[my.myArray retainCount]);

[my release];
```

When i add object "my" to NSMutableArray, the retainCount of "my" was added.
but myArray wasn't. Did it mean that I must retain myArray by my self?
or something other I can do.
Can this code work normal after I release "my" object?

```
[a objectAtIndex:0];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this code actually working? I don't see any connection between a nd my.myArray. myArray is just nil if you did not initialize it in myClass. The owner of myArray is an instance of myClass.

Answer (score 3):

Another great example of exactly why you should...

## NEVER call -retainCount!

retainCount is useless, misleading and a waste of your time.

In this case, the reason why the retain count happens to be zero "unexpectedly" is because `my.myArray` returns `nil`.  *That* happens because you never assign the created mutable array to `myArray`.

You need something like this (Class name capitalized to follow convention):

```
MyClass *my = [[MyClass alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
my.myArray = a;
[a addObject:my];
```

Note that this creates a retain cycle between `my` and the array.  I.e. you will need to remove `my` from the array manually (or remove the array from `my` manually) whenever you release `myArray` and, of course, you can't do that in `dealloc` because `dealloc` will never be called until `my` has been removed from `myArray`.

Comment: Is it my imagination or have you had to say "never call -retainCount" with greater frequency lately?

Comment: It seems to happen in waves...  days with nothing then three or four questions all at once.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that is the full source code above but for my.myArray to be retained you have to actually assign something to it.

So in your above example you created an NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

And then you added your class to it:

```
[a addObject:my];
```

But no where have you created an array and assigned it to myClass as in:

```
NSArray *anArray = [[NSArray alloc] init.....];
my.myArray = anArray;
```

At that point, myArray will get a reference to an object and will retain it (since you specified retain in your myArray prop declaration).

Perhaps if you clarified what it is you are trying to do or posted some more full source code?